# Zabbix - добавить триггер к элементу данных через API

Tags: zabbix

Не могу найти как в Zabbix 3, **[через API добавить созданный триггер](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/trigger/create)** (trigger) к элементу данных (item). Узел сети, элемент данных, триггер получается создать, но как привязать его к элементу данных не пойму.
Возможно кто-то сталкивался?  Делаю на PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя создать триггер без привязки к элементу данных. Когда в нем прописываешь условия expression, триггер автоматически привязываешься к итему,  указанному в условии. Если указывается несколько итемов  - привязываешься к одному из них.